# Как реализовать кнопку inline 'на главную' чтобы при нажатии на нее пользователя перекидывало на /start?

Tags: python, aiogram

Как реализовать кнопку inline 'на главную' чтобы при нажатии на нее пользователя перекидывало на /start?

```
@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def start_callback(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    if callback_query.data == 'start':
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=callback_query.from_user.id, text='<b>✅ Вы вернулись на главную страницу</b>', parse_mode="html")
```

`keyboards.py`:

```
start = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
start_btn = InlineKeyboardButton(text=' На главную', callback_data='start')

start.insert(start_btn)
```

Comment: А чем отличается start от не start? Там какое-то меню определенное или текст?